# android Splash screen resolution 640x960(320dpi)

Tags: android, splash-screen

I had made the android splash screen of resolution 640x960(320dpi) and the screen in getting compressed on the samsung s3 mini. what should i do??

Comment: **Post somecode**: Have you set the layout `params` of `width` and `height` as `match_parent`.... I think instead of  `match_parent` ... u r having `wrap_content` for the image view?

Comment: show layout specify what is the `image resolution` of drawables' folder

Comment: Since the Samsung S3 mini is an hdpi device, I suggest you to make the images 480x720, which is `((640x960) / 2) * 1.5` (xhdpi to hdpi). Obviously, put the graphics into the drawable-hdpi folder.

Comment: i m with @Funkystein

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but Splashscreens are evil, only use them if your employer/client forces you to. See: http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/ and http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

Answer (score 1):

### Steps

- Place the appropriate images in `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-ldpi`,
  `drawable-mdpi` with appropriate resolutions
- Make sure you are having `match_parent` for `width` and `height` of the
  image view and not `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

use scaleType="fitXY" attribute in imageview 
and if application is crashing use lazy loader.

Comment: Please collaborate why one should use the lazy loader and what is is, inexperienced users might not understand this.

Comment: Don't explain it to me ;) But rater edit your answer to make it better understandable for inexperienced programmer's.